# Why isn't Pamac store showing any applications in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman, application

Why isn't Pamac store showing any applications in Arch Linux?. This is what Pamac store is saying: No package found. I installed Pamac store in Arch Linux using this guide: https://www.fossmint.com/pamac-arch-linux-gui-package-manager/. It was available in the AUR. Please see the screenshot:[image: Pamac error]

### This is what I get when I run it through terminal:

```
(process:27467): As-WARNING **: 11:17:15.036: Ignoring invalid AppStream file /usr/share/app-info/xmls/community.xml: Failed to parse /usr/share/app-info/xmls/community.xml file: Error on line 4239 char 4: <p> already set 'Solaar' and tried to replace with ' is a Linux manager for many Logitech keyboards, mice, and trackpads that connect wirelessly to a USB, Lightspeed, or Nano receiver, connect directly via a USB cable, or connect via Bluetooth. Solaar does not work with peripherals from other companies.
  '
(process:27467): As-WARNING **: 11:17:15.105: Ignoring invalid AppStream file /usr/share/app-info/xmls/extra.xml: Failed to parse /usr/share/app-info/xmls/extra.xml file: Error on line 106446 char 6: <p> already set '
      The ' and tried to replace with ' command-line tool allows to read, write, and transform AppStream XML or YAML metadata
      as well as to validate it for compliance with the specification.
      It also provides easy access to the system metadata pool, for example to query for software that provides a
      specific Mediatype handler or for installing software by its component identifier.
    '
Gtk-Message: 11:17:15.159: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-modulegtk-modules"
Gtk-Message: 11:17:15.159: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
(pamac-manager:27467): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 11:17:15.703: gdk_window_set_cursor: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
```

Please help

Comment: Can you run `pamac-manager` from the terminal and add the output?

Comment: Ok, I have added the terminal output.

Comment: Please [don't post an image of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It makes it harder to search for the error.

Comment: Ok,I have added the text of the output that I get in the terminal